# Android: Value is being converted to 0 or 1 right before insertion to a room database

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm trying to store a entity with a foreign key into my room database. Let's say I have the field, which is the foreign keys value, set to 6. I followed it all the way until it's inserted and it stays 6, but for some reason it gets stored as 0. If I don't have an instance on the Parent Room Database of 6, it will crash as expected. But even when it does exist, it gets stored as 0. If it's an odd number, it get stored as a 1. Here's some code that is relevant:

```
@Entity(tableName = "order_table",
        indices = {@Index(value = "shift_id")},
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Shift.class,
                        parentColumns = "id",
                        childColumns = "shift_id",
                        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)})
public class Order {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "shift_id")
    private int shiftId;


    public Order(int shiftId) {
        this.shiftId = shiftId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getShiftId() {
        return shiftId;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
```

```
@Dao
public interface OrderDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Order order);
}

   @Query("SELECT * FROM order_table WHERE shift_id = :shiftId")
    LiveData<List<Order>> getAllOrdersFromShift(int shiftId);
}
```

```
public class OrderRepository {

    private OrderDao orderDao;

    public OrderRepository(Application application) {
        ShiftsDatabase database = ShiftsDatabase.getInstance(application);
        orderDao = database.orderDao();

    }

    public void insert(Order order) {
        new InsertOrderAsyncTask(orderDao).execute(order);

    }
  public LiveData<List<Order>> getAllOrdersFromShift(List<Integer> ids) {
        return orderDao.getAllOrdersFromShift(ids.get(0));
    }

 private static class InsertOrderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Order, Void, Void> {
        private OrderDao orderDao;

        public InsertOrderAsyncTask(OrderDao orderDao) {
            this.orderDao = orderDao;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Order... orders) {
            orderDao.insert(orders[0]);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class OrderViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private OrderRepository repository;

    public OrderViewModel(Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new OrderRepository(application);
    }

    public void insert(Order order) {
        repository.insert(order);
    }
    public LiveData<List<Order>> getAllOrdersFromShift(int shiftID){
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        ids.add(shiftID);
        return repository.getAllOrdersFromShift(ids);
    }
}
```

NOTE: I know the array list seems unnecessary, but I just removed the code that made it necessary for simplifying.

```
public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {

    private OrderViewModel orderViewModel;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private int shiftId;
    private Button saveButton;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable       Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_fragment, container, false);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.tipsRecyclerView);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this.getActivity(), LinearLayout.VERTICAL));
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        final OrderAdapter adapter = new OrderAdapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        orderViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(OrderViewModel.class);

        orderViewModel.getAllOrdersFromShift(shiftId).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<Order>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Order> orders) {
                adapter.submitList(orders);
            }
        });
    saveButton = view.findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

  saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Order newOrder = new Order(shiftId);
                orderViewModel.insert(newOrder);
    }
}
```

If you change the shiftId in the getAllOrdersFromShift to 0, it will display some records. A weird symptom is if I try to store an order to a shift with a shiftId of 0, I get a foreign key error.

I did find someone who had a similar issue here: [Room database: inserted ID is always 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53266920/room-database-inserted-id-is-always-0)

They were just using Kotlin and I don't know it yet.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being a problem with the query which wouldn't have been able to be detected here because I thought it wasn't important. Turns out it was